# Using 'goto' to move from if to else

Tags: java, string, break, goto, continue

I know that there's no `goto` in java, but I ask on general if there are a method to `goto` from if to else
example :

```
public void decToAsci(String decimal) {
    String nb = "";
    int number;
    for (int i = 0; i < decimal.length(); i++) {
        Character c = decimal.charAt(i);
        if (!c.equals(' ')) {
            nb += decimal.charAt(i);
            if (i == decimal.length() - 1)
                //here i want to jump to else
                // i can do it like this :
                // System.out.print( (char) Integer.parseInt(nb) + " ");
                // but i repeat code in else here ..i just want to jump to else 
        } else {
            number = Integer.parseInt(nb);
            System.out.print((char) number + " ");
            nb = "";
            number = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I try this :

```
if (!c.equals(' ')) {
    nb += decimal.charAt(i);
    if (i == decimal.length() - 1) continue label;
} else {
    label: the code in else
}
```

But not worked, not worked with break label also. I understand that continue, break. Are used between son and parent like that? :

```
label:
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    if (cond) break label;
```

I ask about a method that can jump from if to else (2 sons)

(not a son and a parent but jumping between 2 sons )

*I think even with `goto` on c and c++ 4 example we can't do it*

Comment: Use a method. Call the same method from your if block and your else block. That's how you avoid code duplication. You write a method containing that code and call it from multiple places.

Comment: is this the only solution ?

Comment: Change `if(i==decimal.length()-1) continue label;`  to  `if(i!=decimal.length()-1) {/*do what you need*/};`

Comment: not worked , i think that u dont understand my question .
thanks anyway ..

Comment: @FakhRi if you want to write maintainable, readable code, then yes, it's the only solution. If you want to write spaghetti, unreadable and unmaitainable code, then goto and switch fallthrough is what you need.

Comment: @JBNizet got it (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that uses "goto like" behavior is a bad idea.  It is widely accepted that goto-like control structures lead to code that is a lot more difficult to read / maintain than if you stick to "structured programming" control structures.

Here are (IMO) two "right approaches" to solving the problem:

Approach #1 - rearrange the logic

```
public void decToAsci(String decimal) {
    String nb = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < decimal.length(); i++) {
        Character c = decimal.charAt(i);
        if (!c.equals(' ')) {
            nb += decimal.charAt(i);
        }
        if (c.equals(' ') || i == decimal.length() - 1) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(nb);
            System.out.print((char) number + " ");
            nb = "";
        }
    }
}
```

(If the `c.equals(' ')` was expensive you could use a temporary variable to avoid recomputing it.  In this case, it is cheap, and will probably be inlined and further optimized by the JIT compiler.)

Approach #2 - refactor code into a methid

```
public void decToAsci(String decimal) {
    String nb = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < decimal.length(); i++) {
        Character c = decimal.charAt(i);
        if (!c.equals(' ')) {
            nb += decimal.charAt(i);
            if (i == decimal.length() - 1)
                nb = processAsInt(nb);
        } else {
            nb = processAsInt(nb);
        }
    }
}

public String processInt(String nb) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(nb);
    System.out.print((char) number + " ");
    return "";
}
```

In this context, the first approach gives a better code.  (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have `goto`. But, if I understand you, you might use a `switch`, the default behavior is *fall-through* so something like

```
int number;
for(int i=0 ; i<decimal.length() ; i++ )
{
    Character c = decimal.charAt(i);
    switch (c) {
    default: // <-- c is not ' '
         nb += decimal.charAt(i);
         if (i != decimal.length() - 1) { 
             break; 
         }
         // i == decimal.length() - 1, fall-through  
    case ' ': // <-- c is ' ', or it fell through
        number = Integer.parseInt(nb);
        System.out.print( (char) number + " ");
        nb = "";
        number = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I love your solution .. very interesting

Comment: I hate it!  I'd hate it even more if I had to maintain it.

Comment: it's a solution at least ..
but we need a real solution to jump from 'if' to 'else'

Comment: @FakhRi, no, you don't need that. Believe me. You need to learn using methods. **All** experienced programmers agree that goto is a mess. And that's why Java and all modern languages don't have goto.

Comment: i can use methods but in this case (my exemple) personally , i find it very useful ..  I agree with you about goto on general : )

Comment: @FakhRi To be honest, if your code relies on a weird jump that goes against the logical flow then something's broken

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not think this through correctly. An if-else statement is designed in such a way that you can't jump from the `if` branch to the `else` branch. The whole point of an if statement is to make it clear that "if this is true, do this, otherwise do that." Trying to violate this by using dirty tricks will only lead to maintenance problems. Your code will become very difficult to understand.

Instead of thinking about how to break the if statement, why not find a workaround? What you seem to be doing here is just reading integers separated by white space. If that's what you are doing, why not append a `' '` character to the end of the string before the loop? This will achieve the same thing as the condition `i == decimal.length() - 1`

```
decimal += " ";
String nb = "";
int number;
for (int i = 0; i < decimal.length(); i++) {
    ...
```

Or you can use a `Scanner`:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(decimal);
while (s.hasNextInt())
    System.out.print(((char)s.nextInt()) + " ");
```

Comment: Hi man , Answering your quest : 
[why not append a ' ' character to the end of the string before the loop?]  ==>   at first , i did that , after I decide to bypass it as i forget alot and i'll send it 4 some friends .. \n

good solution with Scanner also . 

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For scientific purposes only. I do not recommend that. Do not try this at home.

```
label1:
{
    label: 
    if (condition1) {
        if (condition2) {
            // OK
            break label1;
        } else {
            // I've changed my mind. I want to go to the else statement
            break label;
        }
    }
    // Substitute of "else"
    // Code here will be executed if condition1 is false
    // ... or if condition1 is true but condition2 is false
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).